# Draw mouse pointer in a position without changing its actual position

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse-cursor

In my WPF application, I have a canvas with a grid in the background. The idea is, once the cursor has entered the canvas (and the mousemove event is being fired), to draw the mouse pointer  as it moves only in the grid intersection closest to its actual position, without - logically - changing it (since otherwise i would be stuck in an intersection and would never be able to calculate the proper intersection where it should be drawn), until it has reached an intersection closer to its actual position than the current one. Can't seem to use

```
Cursor.Draw()
```

because System.Drawing.Graphics is not WPF...

Comment: Try look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201775/wpf-drawing-own-cursor-nontrivial-problem or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805/custom-cursor-in-wpf

Comment: Since you very specifically do *not* want to use the mouse cursor, there's very little point in actually trying to use a cursor.  It only has to look like one, any suitable bitmap will do.

Comment: I guess it is simpler to make that. Thanks Hans.